# Focus at the first field with forEach function

Tags: javascript

I try with `field.first().focus();` but i receive this message in console :

Uncaught TypeError: Object #HTMLInputElement has no method 'first'

I think i'm missing a step but i don't now wath.

```
<script>
    function richiesti() { //open function richiesti

    var dati=0;
    var cognome=document.clienti.cognome;
    var nome=document.clienti.nome;
    var codfisc=document.clienti.codfisc;

    [cognome, nome, codfisc].forEach(function (field) { // open function field
       if (field.value){ // open if value
            dati++;
            } // close if value
       else { // open else value
            field.className = "bg_orange text-sx c_white b";
            field.value = "richiesto" ;
            field.focus(); // i need the focus at first field 
       } // close else value
    }); // close function field

    if ( dati == 3 ){  // open if dati

        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$/;
        var codiceFiscale = document.getElementById("codfisc");

        if (codiceFiscale.value.search(pattern) == -1) { // open if codiceFiscale
            alert("Il valore inserito non è un codice fiscale!");
            codiceFiscale.value = "";
            codiceFiscale.focus();
        } // close if codiceFiscale
        else { // open else codiceFiscale 
            document.clienti.submit() ;
        } // close else codiceFiscale
    } // close if dati 

    else { // open else dati
        alert('Cognome, Nome e Codice fiscale sono campi obbligatori.');


    } // close else dati    
} // close function richiesti 
</script>
```

This is the form with input fields :

```
<HTML>
<table class="half" >
   <tr>
   <td class="tdocra c_white  b">Cognome :</td>
   <td><input name="cognome" id="cognome" type="text" class="text-sx" value="" ></td>
   <td class="tdocra c_white  b">Nome :</td>
   <td><input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" class="text-sx" value=""></td>
   <td class="tdocra c_white  b">Codice Fiscale :</td>
   <td><input name="codfisc" id="codfisc" type="text" class="text-sx" value="" onChange="richiesti();"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</HTML>
```

REVIEW CODE

I add a variable and part of code like a suggestion.
It work fine and now it change the class and the value only for the first field void.

```
<script>
function richiesti() { //open function richiesti

    var dati=0;
    var cognome=document.clienti.cognome;
    var nome=document.clienti.nome;
    var codfisc=document.clienti.codfisc;

    var first = true; // add variable

    [cognome, nome, codfisc].forEach(function (field) { // open function field
       if (field.value){ // open if value
            dati++;
            } // close if value
       else { // open else value
             if (first) { // set focus to first only
               field.className = "bg_orange text-sx c_white b";
               field.value = "richiesto" ;
               field.focus();
               first = false; // after the first one has focus
             }
       } // close else value
    }); // close function field

    if ( dati == 3 ){  // open if dati

        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$/;
        var codiceFiscale = document.getElementById("codfisc");

        if (codiceFiscale.value.search(pattern) == -1) { // open if codiceFiscale
            alert("Il valore inserito non è un codice fiscale!");
            codiceFiscale.value = "";
            codiceFiscale.focus();
        } // close if codiceFiscale
        else { // open else codiceFiscale 
            document.clienti.submit() ;
        } // close else codiceFiscale
    } // close if dati 

    else { // open else dati
        alert('Cognome, Nome e Codice fiscale sono campi obbligatori.');


    } // close else dati    
} // close function richiesti
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your issue?

Comment: @Xotic750 This is link for demonstrating [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geomo/464uT/2/) with some translation italian/english for the input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable so you only apply focus in the first iteration that matches the else condition in your loop

```
var dati=0;
var cognome=document.clienti.cognome;
var nome=document.clienti.nome;
var codfisc=document.clienti.codfisc;

var first = true; // add variable

[cognome, nome, codfisc].forEach(function (field) {
   if (field.value){ // open if value
        dati++;
   } else {
        field.className = "bg_orange text-sx c_white b";
        field.value = "richiesto" ;

        if (first) { // set focus to first only
            field.focus();
            first = false; // after the first one has focus
        }
   }
});
```